# How to select only one image at a time in UICollectionView IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I want one image select at a time.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    for (int i=0; i<[_selectedAssetArray count]; i++) {
    if (i==indexPath.row)
    {
        _Imagebtn.selected=YES;
    }else
    {
        _Imagebtn.selected=NO;
    }
}
```

In this program `_imagebtn` is the `UIButton` ,that is use for to select the image (checkmark image).
& `_selectedAssetArray` is the Array of `UICollectionView` that displays the Image in UICollectionView...

I want one image select at a time for Edit the Image ..So,please help me

Comment: You need to take button on collection view's cell, and maintain a dictionary for each collection item, because it uses the same cell multiple times. _Imagebtn should be subview of collection cell.

Answer (score 4):

If this image is collection item you can use `allowsMultipleSelection` property on UICollectionView object, it's:

> A Boolean value that determines whether users can select more than one
>   item in the collection view.

```
self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;
```

Comment: You can add it to viewDidLoad method. just replace collectionView with the reference you your collectionView.

Comment: You also needs to implement delegate, see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090657/uicollectionview-allows-multipleselection-not-working-xcode?answertab=active#tab-top)